# Pecentages and padding don't add up correctly

Tags: html, padding, percentage, css

I have two `labels` inside a `div` that's `width` is `75%`, and its `max-width` is `700px`. The `labels`, when set to `width: 49%`, `padding` (or `margin`) `:1%` and `display: inline-block`, don't display next to each other or stick out over the edge of the container. However, when the `width` is `49.5%`, they do until the containing `div` is less than its `max-width`. I have tried setting the `box-sizing` to `border-box`, but it only helped a little.

I've also tried using a pixel `padding` instead of a percent, but that didn't work at all.

Here is the relevant code:

```
#container {
  width: 75%;
  max-width: 700px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  box-shadow: #d3d3d3 0px 0px 30px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 10%;
  background-color: white;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 49%;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 1%;
}

input {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 24px;
  padding: 0px 3px 0px 6px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

[image: wrong]

[image: Right]

Comment: Can you show us some html/css that you have tried, you didnt mention the inputs at al in your text.

Comment: Sorry, the labels wrap around the inputs.

Comment: And the inputs has width: 100%?

Comment: Yes. I have added the relevant CSS

Answer (score 2):

49% + 49% + 2% + 2% = 102%

Change

```
 padding: 1%;
```

to

```
padding-right: 1%;
```

Comment: It's less obvious, but it still happens, and now there's no spacing around the `labels`. http://snag.gy/ltHNg.jpg

Comment: You can make input width to something 97% ; you have given input width 100% as well as padding: 0px 3px 0px 6px; which is more than 100% width

Comment: I've found that making the total width 99% usually solves a lot of those problems, especially the overlap, better to go 'not enough' than 'too much'

Answer (score 2):

It can all be fixed with display: block; and box-sizing: border-box;

```
label {
  display: block; //inline-block gives a spacing between the elements.
  float: left;
  width: 49%;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 1%;
}

input {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 24px;
  padding: 0px 3px 0px 6px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box; //without this the input is 100% + 9 pixels wide. which gives the unwanted effects
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Here is a working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TSxec/1/